# What does registering a call for cell reuse actually do?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I don't totally understand what registering a class for cell reuse does. I understand how we use reuse identifiers on cells, I just don't understand what calling this method in viewDidLoad does. Looked at a bunch of docs. Not clicking, n00b here. Could someone give me some tips on what it does please?

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register Class for Cell Reuse Identifier
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Did you read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS"? This is covered there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `UITableView`. It has a datasource that provides it `UITableViewCell`s. To save memory and processor cycles, it unloads `UITableViewCell`s that are no longer on screen and puts them into a reuse queue. When it loads a new cell, the datasource will typically ask the `UITableView` for a cell from this reuse queue. If the queue is currently empty, `UITableView` will construct a new `UITableViewCell` using the class provided. The `reuseIdentifier` is used to distinguish this particular cell type queue from another cell type queue within the same `UITableView`.

Something like this:

`UITableView`: "Hey, Datasource! Give me the cell for this indexPath."

`Datasource`: "Alright. That's a 'foo' kind of cell. Got any of those kicking around that you're not using?"

**No class registered; reuse cells returned from datasource previously**

`UITableView`: "Yes, I do. Here you go."

**No class registered; no cells available**

`UITableView`: "Nope. Hey, I don't have a class registered for that kind of cell. Hmm. Here's `nil` instead."

**Class registered; reuse cells returned from datasource previously**

`UITableView`: "Yes, I do. Here you go."

**Class registered; no cells available**

`UITableView`: "Nope. But I have a class registered for that identifier. Here's a new instance."

Comment: This is answer of the year. The first case though shouldn't it be create a new instance and not reuse as the class isn't registered.

Comment: No, if the datasource has previously created an instance by itself using `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:... reuseIdentifier:@"foo"]`, then the `UITableView` will add it to the `foo` reuse queue when it is offscreen.

Comment: Think I got it, so this needs to be implemented in the viewDidLoad method. What about the interface builder, as mentioned below you can set a cell reuse ID, is this different to registering the class?

Comment: If you set the reuse identifier in interface builder (and connect it to your table view?), you won't need to register the class in `viewDidLoad`. You may not need to connect it explicitly after assigning a reuse identifier. I'm not sure. I don't use Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a class is only needed if you use custom TableViewCells classes If you're using storyboards you can also do this in the Interface Builder.

Comment: I am using custom cells built in the interface builder

Comment: @Kex If you have custom class files for these cells you can define them in the interface builder. ([See this image](http://cl.ly/image/1037071k1h09)) It's fine to remove the line from viewDidLoad.

Comment: ohh that's it, so you only need to have that in the viewDidLoad if you aren't setting the cells programmatically? That line just does the same as typing in a reuse identifier in the interface builder?

Comment: @Kex sort off. You could see it as a more advanced option for the identifier. I would recommend to read some more docs about `UITableviewCell`s