# editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath both are not working together

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `TableViewCell.xib` file wherein each cell there can be the summary of data like name, contact etc. Now if I touch the cell it will go to another ViewController where there will be details of that cell's data.(it does not matter what this ViewController shows). I want to go to another ViewController from this xib file's cell touch. how can I do that.

**CallHistoryTableViewCell.h**

```
@interface CallHistoryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *contactName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *contactNumber;
@end
```

this class has `CallHistoryTableViewCell.xib` file.

**CallHistoryVC.h**

```
@interface CallHistoryVC : UIViewController
@end
```

**CallHistoryVC.m**

```
#import "CallHistoryVC.h"
#import "CallHistoryTableViewCell.h"

@interface CallHistoryVC ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,CallingViewControllerDelegate> {
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<RecentCall> *sortedEventArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tView;

@implementation CallHistoryVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

[self defaultViewSetting];
_tView.delegate = self;
_tView.dataSource = self;
_tView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 75;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _sortedEventArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CallHistoryTableViewCell";
CallHistoryTableViewCell *cell = (CallHistoryTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 //do something
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
@end
```

Now problem is my `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is working fine but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. I have gone through many solutions and added the line `_tView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;` but not working.

Please help

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing the list in the TableView? If yes, pls share your screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot added please check.

Comment: As you're using XIB file for the CallHistoryTableViewCell, Have you registered your CallHistoryTableViewCell cell in ViewDidLoad? I don't see the code for that.

Comment: great!!! its working. Without registering everything working except didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Is it on necessary for xib file for registering in viewDidLoad? because I register cell at cellForRowAtIndexPath. Can you Please explain me please.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440046/what-does-registering-a-call-for-cell-reuse-actually-do

Comment: Another thing is I want to send the selected indexpath.row number to the viewcontroller. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146352/discussion-between-imad-and-sazid008).

Comment: Please check at chat box