# Register UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to register `UITableViewCell` in `viewdidload`

```
self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

In cellForRowAtIndex

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell  

    cell.productNameLabel.text = "Product"
    cell.productNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

    return cell
}
```

Here it is crashing in `cell.productNameLabel.text`.

What is the purpose of registering cell? why it is crashing? 
I want to reload data even if cell or table is not visible.

Crashreport : [image]

Comment: show your crash report

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440046/what-does-registering-a-call-for-cell-reuse-actually-do) to know purpose of registering cell

Comment: Be aware that If the cell is designed as prototype cell in Interface Builder you **must not** register the cell

Comment: If you are creating xib for CustomTableViewCell then you should do registerNib, else no need to register cell if you are doing from UITableView it self

Comment: What crash report you got? @Cintu

Comment: crash report updated in my question. @vadian - I will remove register cell then thanks

Comment: The reason of the crash could also be that the `UILabel` in the custom class is not connected in IB.

Comment: @vadian -  Its connected. I had a different problem to solve that I tried register cell. I will ask different question then.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the Apple's comments which answers your query on the purpose of registering cell :

> Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the
>   register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:) method to tell the table view how
>   to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently
>   in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to
>   create a new cell object automatically.

This is the standard procedure I apply while working with Custom Cells (if you are using xib) :

1. Set cell's identifier in Xib's attribute inspector :

[image]

2. Register Xib :

   ```
   self.tableTasks.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "taskCell")
   ```

However, if you are not using Xib and creating custom cell using code only, then use registeCell :

```
self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a xib for this cell? If so, none of the outlets will be connected if you just register the class of the cell. You need to register the actual xib file, so that everything can be connected correctly when the cell is created. Have a look at

```
-(void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-registernib

Answer (score 0):

My method for register cell.

#### Syntax sugar

```
protocol BSCellProtocol {
   // For `registerCell`
   static var NibName: String! { get }
   // For `registerCell`, `dequeueCellWithType`, and `dequeueHeaderFooterWithType`
   static var Identifier: String! { get }
}

extension UITableView {
    func registerCell(_ type: BSCellProtocol.Type) {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: type.NibName, bundle: nil)
        let identifier = type.Identifier!
        self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    func dequeueCellWithType<T: BSCellProtocol>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: type.Identifier) as! T
        return cell
    }
    func dequeueCellWithType<T: BSCellProtocol>(_ type: T.Type, index: IndexPath) -> T {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: type.Identifier, for: index) as! T
        return cell
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell, BSCellProtocol {
     static var NibName: String! = "MyCustomCell"
     static var Identifier: String! = "cellIdentifier_at_Xib"

     @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
     // other IBOutlet components
}

// In ViewController, register cell
tableView.registerCell(MyCustomCell.self)

// dequeue cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // cell is `MyCustomCell` instance 
     let cell = tableView.dequeueCellWithType(MyCustomCell.self)

     // configure cell ...
     // ....

     return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had the same problem. I also was not using XIB for cell. My view was not connected to View in File's Owner Outlets. Maybe this info will help someone.